# Java CrystalReports issue : Can not create temp file: Missing parameter values.---- Error code:-2147215357

Tags: java, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Can any help me to resolve this issue . I have been trying to connect to BO server and after connecting and setting the parameters , trying to export it as pdf format, here my code fails saying missing parameter values.

**Below code used to get the ReportClientDocument**

```
IInfoObject infoObject = (IInfoObject) infoObjects.get(0);  

            IReportAppFactory reportAppFactory = (IReportAppFactory) enterpriseSession.getService("RASReportFactory");          
            //Open the report file          
            return reportAppFactory.openDocument(infoObject, OpenReportOptions._refreshRepositoryObjects , Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**Below is code used for setting the parameters :**

```
        ParameterFieldController paramFieldController = clientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();            
        Fields parameterFields = clientDoc.getDataDefinition().getParameterFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterFields.size(); i++) {
            IParameterField paramToChange = (IParameterField) parameterFields.getField(i);
            String field = paramToChange.getName();             

            if (field.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("@"))
                field = field.substring(1);
            else if (field.substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("V_"))
                field = field.substring(2);
            String value = null;
            System.out.println("Fields:  :i= "+i+ "  "+field);
            if (reportParam.get(field) != null)
                value = reportParam.get(field).toString();                
            else
                value = "";


            IParameterFieldDiscreteValue newDiscreteValue = new ParameterFieldDiscreteValue();
            System.out.println("Setting Parameter value :i= "+i+ "  "+value);
            newDiscreteValue.setValue(value);
            ParameterField tempParam = new ParameterField();
            paramToChange.copyTo(tempParam, false);
            if (tempParam.getCurrentValues().size() > 0)
                tempParam.getCurrentValues().remove(0);
            tempParam.getCurrentValues().add(0, newDiscreteValue);
            paramFieldController.modify(paramToChange, tempParam);
```

**Below is the order where I am calling the various methods in order.**

ReportClientDocument clientDoc = getDocumentFromInfoStore(enterpriseSession, crInfo.getReportsFolder(), reportName);

```
    if (!setDatabaseLocation(crInfo,clientDoc, sUserId, isILIReport)) {
        ReportLogger.debug("Error generating " + rptFileName + " report.<br/>" 
                + "Report Following Error Details<br/>"
                + "Database Location could not be set.");
        return null;
    } else if (!setReportParameters(clientDoc,reportParam)) {
        ReportLogger.debug("Error generating " + rptFileName + " report.<br/>"
                + "Report Following Error Details<br>"
                + "Database Parameters could not be set.");
        return null;
    } else if (!setFilter(reportParam, clientDoc)) {
        ReportLogger.debug("Error generating " + rptFileName + " report.<br/>"
                + "Report Following Error Details<br>"
                + "Database Filters could not be set.");
        return null;
    }else if (!setFooterCriteriaInfo(reportParam, clientDoc)) {
        ReportLogger.debug("Error generating " + rptFileName + " report.<br/>"
                + "Report Following Error Details<br>"
                + "Database Filters could not be set.");
        return null;
    }else if (!setSorting(reportParam, clientDoc)) {
        ReportLogger.debug("Error generating " + rptFileName + " report.<br/>"
                + "Report Following Error Details<br>"
                + "Database Filters could not be set.");
        return null;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong , your help is really appreciable !! -Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have resolved this issue . And the solution is as follows

```
IParameterFieldDiscreteValue newDiscreteValue = new ParameterFieldDiscreteValue();
            System.out.println("Setting Parameter value :i= "+i+ "  "+value);
            newDiscreteValue.setValue(value);
            ParameterField tempParam = new ParameterField();
            **paramToChange.copyTo(tempParam, true);**
```

by changing the copyTo method boolean value to true i.e., making a deep copy of the PrameterField Object resolved the issue . i.e.,   **paramToChange.copyTo(tempParam, true);**